# nodejs print file with child-process

Tags: javascript, node.js, system, electron, child-process

I'm learning nodejs and I want to send some file to the printing queue.
I tried elctron-printer and node-printer modules but actually they do not work proprly (can't detect printer with printer.list command for example). Now I'm trying to make it with child_process module and I want to know is there any posibility to start file with its associated application with "print" argument like a python can do it?

For example, this is a code sample of file execution with nodejs:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
childProcess.exec('start printme.txt', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    process.exit(0);// exit process once it is opened
})
```

Unfortunately it seems that "print" argument is invalid for this code.

And this is a code sample for python and it works fine on windows:

```
import os
os.startfile('printme.txt', 'print')
```

All in all I hope that there is possibility to emulate system commands with nodejs.
Otherwise I will have to execute python script via nodejs just for file printing, something like this:

```
let python = spawn('python', [path.join(app.getAppPath(), '..', 'python_scripts/print_file.py'])
```

But it is terrible way to do it.

Comment: _"Unfortunately it seems that "print" argument is invalid for this code."_ Where is that argument in your child spawning code? Do you have a `start` command in your system?

Comment: As [docs says](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) command can be defined with space-separated arguments. I use windows 7 and trying to find out child_process.exec specifics. So `exec('start printme.txt')` works just like `exec('printme.txt')`

Comment: Sure, but your code snippet only shows that you are executing `'start printme.txt'`.

Comment: Yes, but `'print printme.txt'` argument is invalid for this snippet as I said above.

Comment: When Im trying to pass "print" argument in the `exec('print printme.txt')` command it outputs this line of code in the console `�� 㤠���� ���樠����஢��� ���ன�⢮ PRN`

Comment: That is not the same thing as that Python function. By the looks of it, "print" should be the second argument.

Comment: Of course python has completely different syntax, but as for win os the executable command should be exactly the same I think. How to implement the same os "print" command with nodejs just like with python? I realy don't want to include python's script in my nodejs snippet.

Comment: Does it actually work when you manually do it via command line? Try `exec('type printme.txt')` and see if it outputs the file to the console, maybe it just doesn't find your file. If it doesn't then you can try setting `cwd: __dirname` as an option for `exec`.

Comment: Just tried in command line the same script as I wrote above only with "type" argument, as a result it outputs `print testing` into console log. Where does this string come from? It seems that node processes something but wrong.